# Excel 2007 question about random numbers

Tags: random, excel-2007

In cell A1:A50 i have random numbers geberated by formula ( from 0 to 20), now what ever i do these numbers keeps on changing all the time, so i want to know the formula which will shuffle these random numbers automaticallly till the series whcich have got 5-12-19 in a row will appear. I would really appriciate if some one can help me out of this problem...Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think you're going to need a VBA function returning an array. That VBA function will have to continually generate sequences of numbers until it gets what you want (*why* you want this is another matter!).

Sorry - I'm not a VBA whizz, so I can't put this together easily for you.